# @import not working in SASS file in subfolder

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, rubygems, sass

### Setting the stage

I have the following stylesheet structure:

```
/stylesheets   
 |
 |-- /subfolder
 |    |
 |    + styles.css.scss
 |
 + application.css.scss
```

**application.html.haml**

```
  = stylesheet_link_tag "application", media: "all"
  = stylesheet_link_tag "subfolder/styles", media: "all"
```

**application.css.scss**

```
@import "styleguide";
@import "styleguide/base/_all";
@import "styleguide/modules/_all-no-grid";
// Omitting rules not relevant to the problem
```

**styles.css.scss**

```
@import "styleguide";
@import "styleguide/grid/_grid";
@import "styleguide/modules/_all-grid";
// Omitting rules not relevant to the problem
```

The styleguide files live in a gem which serves the assets from `vendor/stylesheets` with help of a RoR engine.

### The Problem

When I run my application in production with pre-compiled assets I am encountering problems pointing to the `@import` for the styleguide.

```
File to import not found or unreadable: styleguide.
Load path: 
 Sass::Rails::Importer([omitted]/app/assets/stylesheets/local/styles.css.scss)
 (in [omitted]/app/assets/stylesheets/local/styles.css.scss)
```

### The Workaround

There is no problem with the styleguide itself, because as soon as I import the `subfolder/styles.css.sccs` file from the `application.css.scss` file everything is working as expected.

**application.html.haml**

```
  = stylesheet_link_tag "application", media: "all"
```

**application.css.scss**

```
@import "styleguide";
@import "styleguide/base/_all";
@import "styleguide/modules/_all-no-grid";
@import "subfolder/styles"
// Omitting rules not relevant to the problem
```

**styles.css.scss**

```
// Same as above, included for completeness
@import "styleguide";
@import "styleguide/grid/_grid";
@import "styleguide/modules/_all-grid";
// Omitting rules not relevant to the problem
```

### Solutions

Has anyone ran into something like this before? Are there any known issues that could cause this to happen?

Comment: If you want to import your scss files into the application scss file you should reference the imports without the '_'... ie. @import "styleguide/base/all";

Answer (score 2):

I'm going to guess this is a simple issue of modifying your path(s) in your styles.css.scss file. If your styleguide directory is not in your subfolder (which it doesn't seem like it is), you will have to point your import paths up a level in styles.css.scss.
If that's the case, just try:

```
@import "../styleguide";
...
```

Because application.css.scss is located a level up, it recognizes these paths during import, where styles.css.scss does not.